# Update media source directory for Final Cut Pro X event

Tags: final-cut-pro-x

While "cleaning" my OS drive, I decided to move all project media files (video, audio and pictures) to my network storage. As expected, Final Cut cannot locate the files, that were tied to my projects.

Is there a function to update the file paths by "scanning" the new directory?

Answer (score 0):

When you link one media file in an event, FCPX should find the other media files automatically.

For example, if you had media files in a folder, then moved the contents of that folder elsewhere, linking one file from that folder back to the FCPX media reference should let FCPX see the rest of that folder and automatically relink the rest of the media from that folder.